# Как остановить Ипатьева и Шиманского?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][Вот скрины[image: ][1]]Я давно тут не была, около года. За это время изменились правила и комментарии теперь можно писать только набрав 50 очков. Это странно, но не было бы критично, если бы Ипатьев и Шиманский не заполонили всё. На данный момент, в какой вопрос ни зайди, там Ипатьев и Шиманский пишут бред, дают глупые советы, не имеющие никакого отношения к вопросам, хамят другим участникам, сами на вопросы не отвечают и мешают отвечать другим. Тех, кто реально даёт правильные ответы на вопросы, эта парочка гнобит, т.е. ставит "Тревогу", а задающим вопросы ставят минусы, чем борются с конкуренцией. Так они не дают другим участникам набрать те самые 50 баллов, а у кого эти баллы есть, они уменьшают их количество. Таким образом, даже если простой участник хотел бы ответить на вопрос, это невозможно.
Вопросы объявляют дубликатами, хотя ничего общего между якобы вопросами-дубликатами нет, и, соответственно, и ответа на вопрос в дубликате нет и не может быть.
В результате получить ответ на простой вопрос на данном сайте проблематично. А был такой хороший и полезный сайт. Неужели нельзя избавиться от двух вредителей?
Здесь есть модераторы? Почему они бездействуют?

---

Глеб, поскольку нет другого способа ответить на Ваш ответ, пишу здесь.

1. Вы можете доказать, что это не они поставили мне 2 минуса? ;)
   Кроме того, я понимаю, за что можно поставить минус за ответ, хотя эту возможность сейчас на сайте убрали, но как и за что можно поставить минус за вопрос? Если человек неграмотно с точки зрения программирования сформулировал вопрос, значит ему требуется помощь в данном вопросе и он просто чего-то не знает. Нормальный человек или разберётся и окажет помощь, или не будет мешать другим сделать это. Именно для этого и существует этот сайт.
2. Никакой т9 в планшете не бывает. У меня ощущение, что некоторые отвечающие думают, что они с рождения умели читать, писать, считать и программировать... Что невозможно, поэтому Ваше хамство в данный момент ничем не мотивировано.
3. Я поставила тревогу два раза и оба их комментария удалили. Но они так много пишут, что устанешь ставить тревогу. К тому же, поставить тревогу я могу только в своих вопросах. А хамят они всем.
4. Хотелось бы узнать, за что сейчас добавляют баллы. Раньше добавляли за плюсы за ответ, за лучший ответ и отнимали за минусы и всё было честно. А сейчас плюсы и минусы убрали, лучший ответ тоже, и, похоже, плюсы ставят просто за количество комментариев. Понятно, что такие плодовитые авторы наберут огромное количество баллов ;) И не важно, что один из них вообще в любом вопросе вставляет один  и тот же совет.
5. Я абсолютно уверена, что ни один человек не задавал вопрос типа "Как находить ошибки?" просто потому, что это всем изучающим программирование и так известно. А вот от чего бывает та или иная ошибка, может знать и ответить только знающий человек с опытом работы. Делая вопросы дубликатом, вы просто лишаете человека возможности получить ответ на вопрос.
6. Вы настойчиво рассказываете про 1000 голосов за ответы, не подскажете, где и как сейчас может поставить плюс или минус за ответ простой участник?
7. Ну и вишенка на торте: у хороших учителей плохих вопросов не бывает :)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152336/discussion-on-question-by-sollita-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 10):

*Итак, господа. В связи с возникновением конфликта в сообществе, моя обязанность как модератора вас угомонить.*

Администрация StackExchange по результатам голосования на выборах модераторов сообщества наделила меня полномочиями для того чтобы я смог это сделать. Тем не менее, при подобном масштабе конфликта решать единолично исход конфликта я не намерен, поэтому согласовал текст этого ответа с большинством из модераторов. Можете считать всё написанное здесь коллективным ответом модераторского состава.

Начну с самого главного - блокировок по результатам текущего обсуждения на Мете не будет. Основанием для блокировки является нарушение [Норм поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct). В текущем обсуждении нарушения были, но так как само по себе обсуждение может расцениваться нами как возникшее в результате провокации, ограничительных мер не последует.

Все скриншоты комментариев, якобы нарушающих Нормы поведения, сделанные на основном сайте, не являются основанием для применения ограничительных мер. Для применения ограничительных мер основанием являются сами комментарии, которые необходимо пометить тревогой, каждая из тревог будет рассмотрена модератором отдельно. Часть из показанных на скриншотах комментариев была удалена мной лично ещё до появления этого вопроса, а тревоги обработаны, поэтому дополнительных действий от меня и других модераторов в этом отношении не требуется.

Однако причина появления этого обсуждения на Мете ясна и вызывает беспокойство. В первую очередь беспокойство о том, что придётся принимать меры, а я не люблю банить участников, которые ранее вносили вклад в формирование базы знаний StackOverflow. Но к сожалению, иногда проходится. Это сообщение воспринимайте именно как попытку избежать блокировок с надеждой на взаимопонимание.

---

Теперь обращаюсь по "нарушителям" нашего покоя, в том числе к тем, кто здесь активно отметился.

Участники **@Ипатьев** и **@АлексейШиманский** уже многократно были в блокировке. И честно скажу, что они не игнорировали этот факт, а изменили свои манеры общения с другими участниками в лучшую сторону. Как минимум, чтобы не попадать в повторную блокировку. Но откровенно говоря, у обоих плохо получается держать себя в руках на постоянной основе. Я настоятельно вам рекомендую убавить градус токсичности. В данном конкретном случае и в первую очередь - в адрес новичков.

Что делать, если появился "очередной" и "банальный" вопрос, а автор вопроса с "первого раза не понимает":

- Закрыть вопрос как дубликат, если он повторяется. Не ленитесь искать дубликаты.
- Отредактировать вопрос, помочь автору с его оформлением.
- Попытаться конструктивно разложить по полочкам автору суть его ошибки в ответе на вопрос. В идеале канонично, в нашем формате базы знаний "вопрос-ответ".
- Если нет терпения/желания - пройти мимо, поставить минус, проголосовать за закрытие вопроса по другим причинам.
- Для всех остальных из ряда вон выходящих случаев есть сигнал тревоги.

Напомню, что ни указания на уровень интеллекта автора вопроса, либо на уровень оформления вопроса, ни отправки в поиски, у нас категорически не приветствуются.

Раз уж заглянул, **@EvgeniyZ**. Вы уже научились не вести долгих бесед с тем, кто вступает с вами в активную полемику. Спасибо за это, но советую не выходить из таких бесед хлопая дверью "удачи" или "всего хорошего". Это токсично. Обратите на это внимание, пожалуйста.

Теперь активная участница **@Dev18**. Охотно вступаете в разногласия с другими участниками, спорите, повышаете градус разговора. Затем трёте свои комментарии (массово), а комментарии собеседника отмечаете тревогами. Это выглядит как ни что иное как намеренные провокации с целью подставить собеседника. Даже если у вас нет намерений подставлять собеседника, зачастую получается именно это. Модераторы это видят и адекватно реагируют. Вдруг вы не в курсе: модераторы видят все удалённые комментарии и историю их правок. По этому поводу несколько комментариев:

- На StackOverflow неприемлема нетерпимость или дискриминация по расовому, гендерному и прочим признакам. Но также StackOverflow не является местом для пропаганды или реализации путей всякого рода равенства и прочих контр-движений, появившихся в противовес этим самым дискриминациям. Мы строим сообщество в первую очередь на основании [Норм поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), а не чего-то ещё.
- Так как вы не приемлете повышения градуса общения в свой адрес - в первую очередь не вступайте в такие обсуждения. Поверьте, специально за вами никто гоняться не будет, чтобы задеть.
- Я не могу удалять каждый комментарий, который вам показался подозрительным или мог быть двояко воспринят. Отсутствие смайликов, и наличие точки в конце комментария - это не проявление пассивной агрессии, это банальное следование правилам русского языка при написании предложений.

---

И всем остальным участникам напомню, что плохо оформленный вопрос, банальность проблемы и непонимание ответа автором вопроса - не причина для проявления возмущения. Мы здесь помогаем всем: и новичкам, и опытным. Начиная писать комментарий помните, что вы пришли сюда помогать. Если ваш комментарий никак не нацелен на помощь собеседнику - не пишите такой комментарий.

Давайте жить дружно. Давайте про программирование писать лучше, хорошо?

*Всем лично упомянутым участникам будут отправлены модераторские сообщения, чтобы они смогли непублично дать обратную связь команде модераторов.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152351/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 9):

Мне кажется, вы не понимаете механику сайта. Давайте рассмотрим ваши претензии подробнее:

1. *Задающим вопросы ставят минусы, чем борются с конкуренцией.*

Ничего подобного. Минусы ставят не единственно эти участники, а вся активная часть сообщества. И уж тем более не для борьбы с конкуренцией (что за ерунда?). Если не хотите получать минусы на посты — пишите качественные посты. Если отключить т9, включить голову и подробно и грамотно охарактеризовать проблему — отрицательного рейтинга не будет. Минусы — это всего лишь средство показать, что с вопросом что-то не так.

2. *Пишут бред, дают глупые советы, хамят.*

Если вам кажется, что они делают что-то, нарушающее правила сайта — ставьте тревогу (и пронаблюдайте, как она будет отклонена). Если бы комментарии *действительно* были бы грубыми — их бы рано или поздно заблокировали бы. А "пишут бред" — это не аргумент. Если участник пишет бред — он не набирает 20+k.

3. *Вопросы объявляют дубликатами, хотя ничего общего между якобы вопросами-дубликатами нет.*

Опять же, вы, вероятно, неправильно понимаете работу сайта. Если вы имеете в виду закрытие дубликатом вопросов на "Как и каким образом находить ошибки в..." — то это просто удобный способ закрыть вопросы типа "вот простыня в 10000000 строк, найдите тут ошибку.". Единолично закрывать вопросы с определенной меткой могут только те, кто имеет золотой знак по этой метке. А для этого нужно иметь золотой знак (1000 голосов за ответы, на минуточку). Мне кажется, человек с золотым знаком должен разбираться в том, является вопрос дубликатом или нет.

4. *Гнобят, т.е. ставят "Тревогу"*.

Примеры? Тревога — это всего лишь знак модераторам, что это не ответ. Даже очень низкокачественные ответы не тревожат. Тревожат только то, что реально не в тему. На хорошие ответы ее ну никак не ставят. И тем более, вы этого увидеть не можете. Абсолютно безосновательно.

*Вывод*:

Никакой проблемы нет. Просто так работает модерация низкокачественных сообщений. Не хотите минусов — задавайте хорошие вопросы.

Comment: Насчет пункта 3 - по идее, дублями должны закрываться те вопросы, которые действительно про одну и ту же проблему. То, что Шиманский все вопросы "что-то не работает в JS" закрывает дублем на вопрос с ответом себя любимого, это лишь его произвол. И это далеко не значит, что он в этом разбирается. Правда, если бы вопросы закрывали с "более правильной" причиной, отвечающим это бы не сильно помогло...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight по вашей логике если закрываются вопросы на дубликат - то это обязательно специально, потому что потешить себя. Ну ей богу, что за детская логика. В этом можно тогда обвинить всех закрывающих дубликаты в которых они присутсвуют.. Смешно, если честно, от таких мыслей

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну обвинять вы первым начали, Grundy например обвиняли, что он произволом дубли закрывает, а теперь выясняется, что вы еще больше этим грешны. И Grundy критику себя не вырезает из сообщений на мете. Если у меня детская логика, то у вас - двойные стандарты?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вы перечитайте тот топик и посмотрите в чём там реальная претензия и что не так. Вы не разобрались в теме, очевидно.........А на мете (и вообще на ресурсе) обсуждаются проблемы, не разбирая по частичкам личности каждого. Так что это вполне резонное и корректное действие. Опять же, согласно правилам, которые вы, видимо, тоже не читали. Всего хорошего. Разговаривать с вами и обсуждать больше не буду (да и опять же, это в правилах - обсуждать в комментариях...и мы вышли из них очередной раз)))

Comment: В данном случае разбирают по частичкам, тк было сказано в вопросе Тс, что "устают подавать отдельные жалобы"... так много комментариев переходящих на личности. И участник, речь о коем на минуточку те Вы @АлексейШиманский с золотым баджем и ведёт произвол

Comment: @Dev18 если сейчас каждый начнёт разбирать каждого, кто кому не нравится (а таких очень много), то ресурс превратиться в базар и помойку. Вашими силами это уже происходит. У ресурса есть инструменты - пользуйтесь... А гневные топики уже все не раз проходили - пишут это всегда одни и те же - неопытные новички, которые считают, что их в чём-то ущемили, хотя им показывают наглядно инструменты для использования. Не отвечают строго на их вопрос, а дают именно инструмент для решения. В итоге люди ведут себя просто как обиженные дети и вместо освоения инструмента бегут плакать, что их якобы обидели.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы говорите абсолютно придуманные вещи, кто кому не нравится, что за нелепость.... Речь о произволе участника/вас и его действиях

Comment: @Dev18 нет, речь идёт об обидках. Даже вы - банально обиженный человек. Потому что привёл цитаты, вырванные из контекста, как написали в комментарии.Например *"мои комментарии игнорируют...окей"* --- это было нападение? атака на человека? произвол? унижение? Нет! Это было обращение внимания на то, что я в другом комменте выше написал решение проблемы участника, а он проигнорировал...Вы же это подали как причину блокировки...серьёзно? Так что да, дело в обидках и в том, что участники явно не разбираются в чём-либо и просто бегут строчить тексты "какие все плохие". Вы это наглядно демонстрируете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне на вас не зачем обижаться, вы это прекрасно знаете, более того, мне стыдно за ваше поведение я другими участниками. Стыдно от имени ресурса. Более того, я бы хотела, чтоб вы изменились и изменили тактику общения с участниками, именно поэтому пришлось войти в этот дым покрытый вашей монополий. Вы первый в классе всех критиковать везде недовольные высказывания, жалобы на того же Грюнди и не раз, а сами.... Ай ай ай, стыдно

Comment: @Dev18 я попробую общаться нежнее)) (это не шутка) Но не как с малыми детьми. Извините, но ресурс, всё же, не для инфантильных деток с нежной психикой

Comment: Пробуйте, Алексей у вас получится, участники верят в вас. И это не сарказм!!! Более того, настоятельно рекомендую просто скопировать текст с ссылкой на док сайта и мирно отправлять тех, кто не связно задаёт вопросы по вашему мнению, более того закрывать вопросы по реальному дубликат у а не без разбору просто жать кнопочку

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не получится, говорю по опыту) У меня бывают часто случаи (не только SO), когда я с улыбкой на лице пишу текст, позитивный текст, а мне в ответ приходит "Ты что кричишь?". Я уже и смайлики пробовал, и улыбки всякие, нет, все равно дают негативную оценку моим комментариям) Так что, тут каждый интерпретирует по своему, а каждому не угодить.

Comment: Не надо смайликов, не надо улыбки вы путаете место нахождение @EvgeniyZ , док на сайт и все, пуанБар!!!!!

Comment: @Dev18 Пожалуйста, подумайте хоть немного о том, что пишете, это раз. Два, вы не единственный человек на SO, и не вам учить меня (да и других) тому, как и какие комментарии писать. Три, сказал человек, который часто использует смайлики в комментариях. Удачи вам в ответе на данный комментарий "доками". Всего наилучшего.

Comment: Да использую, и мои смайлик ни разу не замечены, что я "кричу".... Речь не о смайликах в целом, а о вашем подходе к новым участникам..... Я даже смайлик вставляю(цитата) =>если не получается, как мы поняли по реакциям(мне говорят не кричи) то и не надо тут разводить театр.